# Declared variables are not accessible in other class

Tags: c++

```c++
class crect
{
   CPoint startpt;
   CPoint endpt;
   int lnwidth;

   crect(CPoint from, CPoint to, int wd) //constructor
   {
      startpt = from;
      endpt = to;
      lnwidth = wd;
   }
};

class shape
{
   crect *rect = new crect(from, to, wd); //  wd showing error at this line
};
```

Am using above constructor in shape program then its showing error at wd...

Comment: Do you have `from` `to` and `wd` defined anywhere?

Comment: Where have you defined `from`, `to`, `wd`? Or you trying to access the variables from the constructor of the class, which is never used?

Answer (score 1):

Two things 
first make sure all the variables exist (from to and wd )

Second your constructor is private so you can not create a class object outside the  class . Just think of it like you have a private int a; in your class and you are trying to access a using an object like obj.a;
What you are doing here is similar to singleton design pattern . Where you make the constructor private so that no one can create an object apart from getInstance() method of class .

So declaring constructor as public should solve the problem for you if my guess is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of from, to, wd does not extend outside of the constructor of crect.

Using the same names as the parameters does not work - you need to specify actual values or pass in other variables that are declared in scope.

> [Quick tutorial on Scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Members of a class become `private` by default if you don't indicate the access specifier so to me it seems like both your constructors are `private`.